# osx: tree -I command error opening dir

Tags: macos, shell, tree

I just installed `tree` with `brew`, and when I try to run it like this (on a python project folder):

```
tree -I *.pyc
```

It returns [error opening dir] for the `pyc` files, for example:

I get this running `ls`:

```
a.pyc b.pyc
```

and when I run `tree -I *.pyc`, I get:

```
b.pyc [error opening dir]

0 directories, 0 files
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a problem with `tree`, it is the shell (bash) doing it's filename expansions - also known as globbing.  So what is passed into `tree` is a list of all the file names in the *current* directory ending in `.pyc`.  Only the first filename will follow the `-I` option (`a.pyc`), the others will be seen as directory names.

`tree` wants to do it's *own* globbing (`find` is the same) so you must protect it from the shell by adding quotes:

```
tree -I '*.pyc'
```

The quotes will be stripped off by the shell and will not be seen by `tree`, it will just see `*.pyc`.

In this case either single or double quotes would do the trick, but probably safer to stick with single quotes since other expansions are done inside double quotes.

BTW, when you get this kind of issue use:

```
set -x
```

that will show the command after bash expansions.  Use `set +x` to switch it off.  These can be used on the command-line or in a script for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Surround the wildcard patterns passed to `-I` and `-P` with quotes to avoid globbing:

```
tree -I '*.pyc'
```

From `man tree`:

> Valid wildcard operators are 
>  
>   `'*'` (any zero or more characters)  
>  
>   `'?'` (any single character)  
>  
>    `'[...]'` (any single character listed between brackets)

Answer (score 0):

I got issue with **pass** utility

I created a password named  something like github.com/myaccount and caught the

```
[error opening dir]
```

when I tried to retrieve the password

After rebooting everything got right.